# VBA test connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

We have multiple SQL servers that our front end connects to. We need a test to check which servers are offline at any one time.

The code below works completely fine with an online SQL server but when testing an offline one takes over 30 seconds to timeout. We need this to timeout much quicker as this is a check that will be run regularly

```
Function ConTEST()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim strConnect As String

strConnect = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SERVER;UID=UID;PWD=PWD;APP=Microsoft® Windows® Operating System;DATABASE=DB_NAME"

With conn
.ConnectionString = strConnect
.CommandTimeout = 5
.ConnectionTimeout = 5
.Open
End With

End Function
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this timeout issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to spawn threads to do these checks for you on a regular basis?  That way, the 30 second timeout wouldn't necessarily be a bad thing.

Comment: I think if there's no connection before the timeout, an error occurs. Maybe a simple error handler that checks for conn.State might do it. More detailed approach: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167957/info-extracting-error-information-from-ado-in-vb

Comment: Thanks for the response - I have previously experimented with the error handler - unfortunately it takes about 30 seconds per server before it errors out which is too long. So ideally is there a way to speed up this error?

Answer (score 0):

if it's just a database on the server that is taken offline, then connect to the "master" database in your connection, and run the "DATABASEPROPERTYEX" function to get the status of the database you want to check.

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

With conn
.ConnectionString = strConnect
.CommandTimeout = 5
.ConnectionTimeout = 5
.Open
Set rs = .Execute("select DATABASEPROPERTYEX('yourdb', 'Status') as db_status")
Debug.Print rs(0).Value
.Close
End With
```

if the entire server is taken offline, you may want to ping the server instead from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the response - it is likely to be the whole server taken offline - this server is on a network with other machines which all appear to have the same IP address so any suggestions on how to ping that individual machine?

Comment: have you tried what i suggested? ping is using the basic ping utilitly from the command prompt. i doubt that they would be taking an entire machine offline. google for ping , you will see plenty to help you

Comment: I did try the ping approach - it worked ok when using the local server address but there was no response when using the global ip address. So I don't know if our router was blocking the ping. I did try to ping the global ip address with a port number which had been opened for the sql server but that didn't work either...